# Brightness resets after reboot Lollipop 5.0.2 (happening since factory reset)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, screen-brightness, lg-optimus-l90

I have an LG OPTIMUS L90 running Lollipop 5.0.2 and every time I boot my brightness settings reset from 0% (how I had it before reboot) to random numbers, for example: sometimes 90%, 100%, 77% etc.

My screen timeout also resets from "Never turn off screen" to "Turn off after 2 minutes". My device isn't rooted and I just factory reset it. Solutions?

Comment: Did you install any new apps after the reset? One of them may be causing the problem. A workaround would be to use an app like Tasker or MacroDroid to set the brightness and timeout after every boot. Is that solution acceptable?

Comment: When I factory reseted it, before I downloaded any apps it had this problem.Thanks for your answer but I would like it to boot like any other phone and stay with the settings that one chooses for it

Comment: You could just try taking it to the service center and eliminate hardware issues from consideration